# What is this component called? It looks like a table but each row has different types of data

Tags: website-design, gui-design, tables, design, terminology

Looking for a way to distinguish this from a table component but not sure what to call it

[image]

Comment: It may not have a name. I'm not able to think of the benefit of dividing up the details into rows. I searched [user profile examples](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ui+user+profile&t=ffab&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images) and I don't see anything presented like that.

Comment: It looks like a list with two sub-lists that happen to be laid out neatly - I don't think we can recommend a naming convention for this - I also wouldn't recommend presenting this data in this way: how are gender, marital status, job, vet status, income, and city related to each other? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

The elements are lists. To be more precise, it can be called a [Two-line text list.](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/list-design/)

There are three components to a list design:

- The list: All list items together
- List item: An individual item in the list
- List content: The content that makes a list item–image, text, metadata, title, subtitles, and other user interface elements

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **item specific details**.

Comment: I agree. It is basically styling of details using lines and grouping. User Details or Specification could be another proper names for the whole component.